Is our consciousness evidence of the existence of a true ontology that underlies many "conventional" ontologies?
Note: to avoid confusion, this question presumes the correctness of some flavor of physicalism of the mind. The idea that conscious states supervene on the brain. I am making a point that since we have a particular experience with a particular brain state, that somehow that brain state isn't merely a "collection of phenomena" but, in some sense, ontologically fundamental and singular - something is making this spatially separated phenomenon exist as a single thing (experienced moment).
If I am conscious, I am conscious in a certain way. I cannot choose how "red" appears, or what are the nature of my perceptions. Thus, our specific conscious experience is a distinct thing in the universe, determined by some features and patterns in the brain, not by our wishes, frameworks, or worldview.
Contrast this with what I would call "conventional" things like clouds, countries, specific colors, etc. These are things that exist relative to a particular definition, vs really being distinct, foundational components of reality. Sure, water vapor in the sky exists, land masses and natural separations exist, wavelengths are associated with specific visual experiences. But I would argue colors, clouds etc are not fundamental but imposed or invented things defined by some convention.
However, we know this cannot be true for consciousness, because the contents of my consciousness are not dependent on any particular framework, it just is what it is. The fact that this experience is in the world seems to suggest there is an answer to "does X really exist as a thing" vs "does X merely exist by definition".
Speculating further from here, it seems that the real "existents" in our world are defined by some degree of entanglement among spatially disparate components. Thus, the true "ontology" of our world is a complex collection that is always in flux, as things cohere and decohere to varying degrees, with the underlying dynamics being the only constant.
Has anyone run across other thinkers who have addressed this idea of actual things vs nominal things (this is different than noumena vs phenomena - as I am taking our conscious experiences qua experiences as a case where appearances and actuality are identical).

"because the contents of my consciousness are not dependent on any particular framework"... are you certain of that?

@AlistairRiddoch yes

Culture?  Childhood trauma? I have a friend. I subjected her to Bach organ And asked "Isn't it wonderful?" The hesitant response: It hurts my ears. Don't you think Bach is great is a consciousness-experience that is culture  dependent? What about worm cheese?

@Annika You write “the contents of my consciousness are not dependent on any particular framework, it just is what it is.” But we know that the content of our consciousness can easily change due to mental disorders, brain lesions or in extraordinary mental states. Hence it depends on boundary conditions of our brain. - Could you please clarify and elaborate on the penultimate section of your post. What is your point?

@JoWehler - that's my point - if we take physicalism seriously then our experiences are created by the brain, there is no extra "experiencer" that adds a layer on top of it. We (as experiencers) are constituted by the experience produced by our brain. The fact that we exist as experiences (assuming no soul) means that nature somehow decides that this particular grouping of matter and energy maps to this particular experience  means that that experience is single thing vs just a collection of things we group by definition or conceptually.

"The fact that we exist as experiences (assuming no soul) means that nature somehow decides that this particular grouping of matter and energy maps to this particular experience means that that experience is single thing vs just a collection of things we group by definition or conceptually." Nature decides nothing as decisions are the products of agents, and nature, unless anthropomorphized, is no agent. I'd also encourage you to read up on embodied cognitition. Cognition doesn't just occur in the brain.

@JD - I was speaking metaphorically. Also not sure how embodied cognition is relevant at it is physicalist as well, it just challenges purely computational models (which I am sympathetic to as well)

You ask:

Is our consciousness evidence of the existence of a true ontology that underlies many "conventional" ontologies.

I think your question is prescient, but I think the terminology "true ontology" is a misapplication of the word 'true' which is best reserved for a correspondence to affairs in the real world or logical coherence among propositions. It would be better to say there is a statistically prevalent ontology that is a function of our embodied cognition which manifests itself according to a certain statistical measure of central tendency of sorts regarding how the body constructs a metaphysical system. One would even expect, that that sort of regularity would manifest itself as some consistent semantics across languages.
In fact, such a proposal has been made in the form of natural semantic metalanguage (NSM). From WP:

Natural semantic metalanguage (NSM) is a linguistic theory that reduces lexicons down to a set of semantic primitives.

Again from later in the article:

Proponents of the NSM theory argue that every language shares a core vocabulary of concepts. In 1994 and 2002, Goddard and Wierzbicka studied languages across the globe and found strong evidence supporting this argument.

Thus, the idea that you are suggesting is that natural kinds and semantic primes are in some way a core and objective measure in terms of assessing the metaphysics of an ontology. Thus, all of the variations of ontology might be a manifestation in the similarity within how human consciousness exists and functions independent of any one person. This seems to me to be a reasonable conjecture.

+1: Very interesting and helpful! Will take some time to digest the links, but I agree with you that "true ontology" is not a good term. I was leaning towards "metaphysically privileged" or something like that, but I suspect Natural Kinds will be a very helpful concept, as you suggest. Will report back after reviewing. Thank you!

@Annika No worries. And for the record, I think natural kinds are exactly what you propose them to be: a metaphysically privileged or received view of the world. I think that this broad-based ontological bias, if you will, in combination with a moderate skeptical/scientific epistemological train of thinking is exactly what Wilfred Sellars attacks as the Myth of the Given as a more contemporary reading of Kant's thinking in Critique of Pure Reason...

"In it, he criticizes the view that knowledge of what we perceive can be independent of the conceptual processes which result in perception. He named this "The Myth of the Given," attributing it to sense-data theories of knowledge. " <- this notion that this privileged ontology shapes our perception itself is a necessary and bold attack on the notion of objectivity-as-independent of the viewer, as in the sense theory-ladenness explains.

You say :

Thus, our specific conscious experience is a distinct thing in the
universe, determined by some features and patterns in the brain, not
by our wishes, frameworks, or worldview.

Conscious experience is definitely dependant upon wishes, frameworks, or worldview too:

Mistaking a rope for a snake, presupposes the knowledge of what a snake is.
Mistaking a person approaching with the one you are expecting to arrive is based on wish.
Mistaking an airplane with a huge bird - if you live outside civilization - presupposes a specific worldview etc.

What is happening, is that external reality is respresented (reconstructed by the brain) inside you. Your conscious experience is an experience of the representation. If we symbolize consciousness with a torch that sheds light upon, it is in this representation that light is shed upon and not on the external things themselves. (A tree - for you - is the representation of the tree inside your brain; consciousness sheds light upon the representation of the tree).
Then, the original sensations (visual, sound, touch etc), your wishes, frameworks and your worldview all together form the "vocabulary" by which your experience is formulated. So, your experience is what you (in all these levels) have made of.
If we think of this "vocabulary" as the "conventional ontologies" as you define, then your question is basically whether a "true onlogoly" exists behind all this.
You say :

... "does X really exist as a thing" vs "does X merely exist by definition" ...

I take this out of context ... and relating it to the previous thoughts, I say that a definition is a meaning (part of our "vocabulary") inside the representation. So the "thing" is identified by the definition we ascribe to it. An then the question comes: Does this "thing" exist outside of us and what is its "true ontology"?
The answer is simple, but difficult to grasp. Of course the "thing" exists outside of you (since it is impossible to have a reflection of a non-existing thing), but what you identify as a "thing" is a definition/meaning that you have ascribed to it: What you think of as external reality is the representation (reflection) of this reality into yourself. But this reflection is not as in a mirror (because of the distortion of senses, beliefs etc.). So what is reflected? What it is. And what is it? Well, you can't know per se, because you can only know things by making definitions out of them and these definitions are the representations of them: You can only know reality by how it appears to you. Welcome to reality! Ha Ha.

I'm not arguing for content externalism or reliabilism. I'm saying that we don't have a say in what conscious state is associated with a particular set of brain patterns in our head. If we re-create the brain state produced by a red circle in the center of your visual field, you will experience a red circle in the center of your vision. Wheter that circle is really there is beside the point.

The question seems to combine several methodologies in inappropriate ways.
Starting with the primacy of experience -- is phenomenalism.  Phenomenalism can, with great effort, be formulated to be semi-compatible with physicalism.  Equating these two, seems to be a major invalid presumption.  Phenomenalism broke down a century ago when what qualia were fundamental and what are derivative could not be agreed upon by phenomenalists themselves.
IF one starts from physicalism, then what is "real" is the underlying physics.  Which -- ISN'T the experience.  Physicalism instead relies upon Identity Theories, where the physical (or for functionalism, the function) is what is fundamental, and the experience is basically an a-causal add-on.
Meanwhile, you refer to experiences as "ontologically fundamental and singular", which is essentialism.  Physicalism, and science in general, has rejected essentialism as a primarily idealist concept.
Kripke was the last major advocate of essentialism, and I have a summary here of how he tried to revive it:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/93974/29339
So -- the ideas include phenomenalism, and physicalism which does not mesh well, plus essentialism.  Some of the Vienna Circle were both physicalists and phenomenalists, most notably Rudolph Carnap, (who can also be classified as an idealist, as I noted, it is a major effort to integrate phenomenalism into physicalism!).  Kripke tried to reintegrate essentialism into philosophy, but I think Kripke was basically an emergent dualist not a physicalist (I suspect he would probably have embraced emergent physicalism if it had been articulated during his time, so like Carnap with physicalism/idealism, Kripke may be ontologically on the border between physicalism and dualism).

Hmm -- I take physicalism as true in my view. Conscious experiences supervenes on the physical. Also, I'm not saying that everything that exists is conscious or any form of idealism.
However, at any moment I have one specific experience that is being determined by some arrangement of physical stuff/fields etc. The fact that there is this 1-1 mapping of physics to experience means there is something about the particular arrangement that is associated with a single thing (the experience). This means that this arrangement is somehow metaphysically privileged.

That is what I mean by ontologically fundamental. I actually like the term I just used better -- under physicalism, the fact that a some arrangements of matter constitute one actual thing (an experience) suggests that the denizens of reality are determined by entangled, spatially extended states. These states/arragments are metaphysically privileged (with our conscious experience being one small example of this, not all of it).

Note that this differs from a simulation, where we merely emulate the functional behavior but by a completely different mechanism. The mechanism seems to matter here. This means while a collection of people is a nation, a collection of NaCL a grain of salt, these are not ontologically singular things, they are simply aggregations.
Something, and I don't know what, gives physical states like the ones that constitute a conscious experience ontological reality, while others are merely collections of these types of states.

@Annika Multiple realization pretty effectively refutes the “special arrangement of matter creates an essence which is identical to a conscious experience” claim.  We have the same experience despite continual rearrangement of our neuronal links.  And we can transmit a meme successfully to others who have very different neurology.  “Thisness” for consciousness is only really compatible with spiritual dualism or idealism.

not sure we ever have the exact experience twice. Also, we don't know what others experience, only that it is internally consistent most of the time.

We cannot do reasoning operations, nor evaluate others reasoning, unless we have effective stability of concepts over massive substrate changes.

Whoops. @Annika

And if 2+2=4 with neural grid at time 1 has “thinness” if the “thisness” comes from the grid not the the concept, then “thinness” would not carry over moment to moment, and we would not feel thisness for 2+2 at time t2.  BUT the uniqueness of thoughts is what motivated your postulation in the first place.  You experience the continuing thoughts as unique.  Even with the varying substrate.

The OP’s post claims that “our specific conscious experience is a distinct thing in the universe, determined by some features and patterns in the brain, not by our wishes, frameworks, or worldview.”

The most simple specific conscious experiences are qualia, e.g., the
experience of a certain colour. Our qualia are generated by the
neuronal wiring of our brain, which has developed during biological
evolution. Hence qualia are shaped by the physical properties of the
human ecological niche.

Of course qualia are not shaped by our wishes or our worldview. But
the content of our conscious processes can easily change in states
of mental disorder, due to brain lesions or in certain extraordinary
mental states like halluzination. Hence I do not see why qualia and
other conscious experiences of living beings should exist in a
specific ontological domain “not dependent on any particular
framework”.

Unfortunately I do not understand what you mean in the penultimate
section of your question by the terms  “the real ‘existents’ ” and
“the true ‘ontology’ of our world”.



The real existents -- as in the fundamental objects the compose reality, vs "conventional existents" like human bodies, comets, etc. For example, a chair is only a thing by convention - its a name for an assembly of wood in a certain way. Contrast this with my current conscious experience -- we cannot pull apart the state that comprises a conscious experience, it is of a piece. So, somehow, this brain state is a single thing vs a collection of things (assuming physicalism). I hope that makes sense, I've had a hard time spelling this out succinctly :)

@Annika Tononi et al. in their paper on IIT 4.0 https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1011465 formulate in the beginning 5 axioms of phenomenal existence. One of them, named Integration (p. 4), reads: “Experience is unitary: it is a whole, irreducible to separate experiences.” Is that what you mean by saying “we cannot pull apart the state that comprises a conscious experience, it is of a piece” ? See also the corresponding postulate of physical existence (p. 5).

Yes — and that experience is instantiated by a spatially extended physical process so we have a clear case of something that clearly exists because it is “us” — this is

One of the seminal authors on “western” Marxism, Georg Lucaks, wrote a powerful (and angry!) critique on Existentialism in which he gives this broad classification of philosophies:

We see clearly that only two positions are possible: either being is primary — materialism, or consciousness is primary — idealism.
Existentialism

With this broad suggestion it is possible to classify a slew of philosophies as idealistic or materialistic; I prefer to use “object oriented” or “subject oriented”:



Object Oriented
Subject Oriented




materialism
idealism


positivism, physicalism, scientism
religion-generally


empiricism
(Platonic) rationalism leading to Neoplatonism


Marxism
existentialism, post-modernism


(logical) positivism, analytic philosophy
taoism, vedanta


objectivism
solipsism




[To be fair, Lucaks point seems to be that Husserl's phenomenology does not quite fit in either column]
Summary
You should find the outlook behind your question consonant with many of the philosophies in the subject oreinted column.
See also
This spectrum of ontologies.
