Metaphysical Impossibility Vs Logical Impossibility
1- Is there any objective way to know what is metaphysically possible or impossible? If something is logically consistent and possible, can u say that the same thing is metaphysically impossible?
2- Do we have any example of something that is logically possible and consistent but metaphysically impossible?
3- How do some philosophers (e.g. William lane Craig) talk about metaphysical impossibility with certainty?

This question is similar to: What exactly is metaphysical possibility?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is no general consensus on the subject, but many writers follow Kripke in holding that statements such as, "Water is H2O" and "Hesperus is Phosphorus" are necessarily true, based on the necessity of identity. Some also maintain that a kind of necessity attaches to statements such as, "If A north of B then B is south of A", "no human being is a number", "anything that is red is coloured", "no person is taller than themselves". These are sometimes described as examples of metaphysical necessity, or conceptual necessity or broad logical necessity.

What is metaphysically possible depends on one's metaphysics just as what is physically possible depends on one's physics. However, there is much less agreement on metaphysics than on physics, so all examples are controversial. If one subscribes to ex nihilo nihil fit, for example, then emergence of something from nothing is metaphysically impossible but logically possible, see SEP for other examples. Craig is a Christian theist so he accepts metaphysics developed in Christian tradition.

Metaphysical necessity, possibility, and impossibility, were basically invented by Kripke as an effort to patch rationality in the face of the realization of the radical contingency of our world.  A contingent world is only explorable through empiricism, not reasoning from logical necessities and impossibilities and reasoning is of little use to bound it.  But if one finds a lesser form of necessity and impossibility, one that is logically possible, but not possible IN THIS WORLD, then rationalism remains useful.  Metaphysical necessity, etc. are all traces to inferred laws of nature, rather than to logic.
Here is a discussion of Kripke's motivation, and my own judgement of his failure. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/93974/29339
OK, trying to answer your questions.
1a) Is there any objective way to know what is metaphysically possible or impossible?

If one can identify a law of nature, then yes.  Note laws of nature are not the "laws" of science.  Science has no necessary laws.  Wikipedia summarizes this:  "scientific laws are simply empirical conclusions reached by scientific method; they are intended to be neither laden with ontological commitments nor statements of logical absolutes."  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_law#:~:text=The%20nature%20of%20scientific%20laws,nor%20statements%20of%20logical%20absolutes.  However, whether there ARE any "laws of nature" has mostly been rejected as an invalid and unnecessary presumption.  See: https://iep.utm.edu/lawofnat/  If we cannot know the laws of nature separate from the merely contingent laws of science, then it is very difficult to discover them "objectively".

1b) "If something is logically consistent and possible, can u say that the same thing is metaphysically impossible?"

Yes, that was the entire idea behind the concept.

2)- "Do we have any example of something that is logically possible and consistent but metaphysically impossible?"

Kripke provided multiple examples.  In my linked answer, I cited reasons to think that all of them are possible under the "laws of science", hence by inference under the "laws of nature", which leaves us without any valid examples of metaphysic impossibility.

3)- "How do some philosophers (e.g. William lane Craig) talk about metaphysical impossibility with certainty?"

William Lane Craig is an Aquinian philosopher, which is a different branch of rationalism than analytic philosophy.  But like analyticity, Aquinian need necessities to do derivations from, so Craig faces the same problems with contingency that other rationalists do. He was therefore attracted to the "metaphysically necessary" concept for the same reason that analytic philosophers were.  And his use of the concept is as subject to criticism of its validity as analyticity is.
Note Kripke primarily relied upon philosopher's intuitions to back up the concept. And the intuitions of analytic philosophers lead to thinking that some aspects of our world are metaphysically necessary.  Likewise, Craig relies upon the intuitions of Aquinian philosophers, and those intuitions lead them to think that some things are metaphysically necessary (most likely different things form analytic philosophers).  An empiricist, would then propose test cases to check these intuitions, as I did with the analytic intuitions. I do not have examples to help you do checks of Craig's intuitions, but you may exercise your own checks when you read him making such necessity claims.
My assumption is that, as with Kripke, Craig's intuitions are out of sync with science.

